Why does charge reside on the outer surface for a conductor but inside in case of an insulator?
So from what I understood, in case of a conductor there are free electrons and when its charged there is maximum repulsion between the like charges which causes the electrons to reside on the surface making the net electric field inside the conductor zero. But I don't get the other case that is for insulators. Please do correct me if I'm wrong with my understanding of theory of charge.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/580309/2451 and links therein.
